# VS 2012 bundles usar ou não usar, eis a questão!

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Estou iniciando no VS 2012 e entre as mudanças apareceu o `bundles`.

Tenho algumas dúvidas:

1 - Vale a pena usar esta abordagem? Por que?

2 - O `bundles` devem mesmo ficar dentro da tag `ScriptManager`

3 - Posso continuar referenciando os `.css` e `.js` da forma antiga?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 - Vale a pena usar esta abordagem? Por que?

Quando falamos em otimização de websites, precisamos atentar para cada detalhe que possa diminuir processamento ou tráfego, usar ***Bundle*** permite você fazer um agrupamento de vários arquivos em um único.

Este agrupamento traz uma série de vantagens na economia de *bytes* trafegados, além de fornecer uma maneira bastante eficiente de organização do projeto.

> 2 - O bundles de mesmo ficar dentro da tag ScriptManager

Não. Você pode usar a classe BundleConfig localizada na pasta App_Start e adicionar/declarar os arquivos que você vai utilizar, por exemplo:

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        ...

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        ...
    }
}
```

Registrar o *Bundle* no método *Application_Start*:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
}
```

E adicionar a referência na página assim:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">        
     <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

> 3 - Posso continuar referenciando os .css e .js da forma antiga?

Sim.

Referências (*em inglês*):

- [Bundling Web Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rickandy/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms)
- [Bundling Web Pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rickandy/adding-web-optimization-to-a-web-pages-site)

Comment: Valeu. Muito esclarecedor. Obrigado!